# updating file with Google Drive API with mimeType html causes margin increase

Tags: python, html, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file using Google Drive (in python), edit some values, saving the file locally and then upload that local file as an update. I am getting the HTML version of the file and uploading using mimeType = "text/html". The edits and uploads work except for the margins or line spacing on headings (h2 & h3) increase slightly each time the script is run.

I have tried putting the content directly into the local file after the download without editing it and the same thing happens (see code below). Has anyone any ideas as to what might be causing this?

KB

```
# get the google drive api object
service = get_service()

# search for file
params = {}
params["q"] = "title = 'Test File'"
values = service.files().list(**params).execute()

# get file
found_file = values['items'][0]

# download file content
content = download_file(service, found_file, "text/html")
f = open('temp.html', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
file = service.files().get(fileId=found_file['id']).execute()

# set the new values
media_body = MediaFileUpload("temp.html", mimetype="text/html", 
                                                        resumable=True)
try:
   # update the file
   updated_file = service.files().update(fileId=found_file['id'], body=file,
                                        media_body=media_body).execute()
except:
   print("error uploading file")
```

Comment: Do you have any html sample that you could share for testing?

Comment: If you're going to round-trip HTML<->docs conversions, test it with a wide variety of sample docs as it's a very leaky conversion.

Comment: Gerardo-the html is generated by Google Drive API. I just have a sample document on that with sample text. some set to heading 2 and heading 3

Comment: pinoyyid - The only reason I am doing it this way is so I can find specific headings and either add some text, highlight it or convert it to a link. Do you know of a better way of doing this?